# sveltekit/vite problem with self signed certificate on localhost

Tags: socket.io, vite, sveltekit

In my dev environment I'm using the basicSsl-Plugin for generating a self-signed-certificate. The website works fine under https until the fetch function is trying to delete a user.

my vite.config.js:

```js
plugins: [
        basicSsl(),
        sveltekit(),
        {
            name: 'sveltekit-socket-io',
            configureServer(server) {
            const io = new Server(server.httpServer);
            io.on('connection', (socket) => {
            const agent = new https.Agent({
            rejectUnauthorized: false
            });
            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                    await fetch('https://localhost:5173/api/users', {
                        method: 'DELETE',
                        body: JSON.stringify({ id: socket.uid }),
                        agent: agent
                    });
        });
    });
```

i get the error `Error: self-signed certificate` and code `DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT`.

when instead of using the basicSsl-Plugin I try using using mkcert-created self signed certificates I cant even access the website anymore with https because I get the following error in the browser: `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';` and now it seems to work. I guess it's fine for development purposes, don't use it on production.